# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel AND The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I have successfully built the Web Application but when I try to view the app in the browser it throws "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel". I tried changing the compile to Debug mode and then it throws "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm" errors.

I have also checked the Regedit.exe for the SSL Protocols and eveything is enabled. I also have the client side test certificate in installed on my machine.

My concern is does the Web Application have the ability to pick the installed certificate from the App Pool or should I write any specific code to use the that particular certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with .NET, but this kind of error typically occurs if the server is not configured to use a certificate. In this case the only ciphers it can offer are ADH etc, i.e. ciphers which don't require a certificate. Because in this case the connection would be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks most clients don't support such ciphers by default and thus you get the error message that client and server have no ciphers in common.